# How to use Mockery v0.0.0-dev in Golang?

Tags: go, mockery

I am trying to generate mocks in Golang using [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery), and the repo requires v0.0.0-dev.

I ran `brew install mockery` but that only installs v2.15.0, and thus cannot generate mocks with v0.0.0-dev. How do I use/install mockery v0.0.0-dev? There is not much info online about this

Comment: "and the repo requires v0.0.0-dev". That's the problem. Upgrade. 0.0.0-dev is unsuitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v0.0.0-dev` is the "[`_defaultSemVer`](https://github.com/vektra/mockery/blob/c943e696a04fb7357ae62ef162e1cf47c171cd4c/pkg/config/config.go#L6)" used by mockery when [`debug.ReadBuildInfo`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/debug#ReadBuildInfo) has no embedded build information.

In your case, the binary installed does include said build information, hence the 2.15.0, which is the latest release, as expected.

You should change the dependency to use an actual version (or, if you have to, use the `@latest`).
Not `v0.0.0-dev`, which depends on how mockery was built.